# Boolean operations on 2D array vs 1D array without looping

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays. One is a 2D array:

```
a = np.array([
    [1,2,3,4],
    [2,5,4,3],
    [4,3,2,3],
    [4,2,1,2]
])
```

The other is a 1D array:

```
b = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
```

Dimensions of `a` and `b` do not necessarily match.

I would like to evaluate the boolean operation `a<b` on all the positions of `a` vs all the positions of `b`. Is it straightforward with a loop over `b` (comparing all elements of `a` to one element of `b` at a time), but **is there a way to do it without loops?**

What I imagine as an output is a 3D array where all positions in `a` are evaluated for all positions in `b`, as follows:

```
array([[[False False False False],
        [False False False False],
        [False False False False],
        [False False False False]],

        [[True False False False],
        [False False False False],
        [False False False False],
        [False False True  False]],

        [[True  True  False False],
        [ True  False False False],
        [False  False True  False],
        [False  True  True  True]],

        [[True  True  True  False],
        [ True  False False True],
        [False  True  True  True],
        [False  True  True  True]],

        [[True  True  True  True],
        [ True  False True  True],
        [ True  True  True  True],
        [ True  True  True  True]]])
```

Comment: Simply extend `b` to `3D` and do : `a<b[:,None,None]`.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!